# Cannot use borgbackup script with sudo as requires ssh password

Tags: borgbackup

I am trying to use borg backup and am running into an issue with SSH. I am backing up some root files such as /var/www/html, therefore I require root permissions, so I need to run the backup script as root, but when I run it as root the SSH key doesn't seem to work, and as it's a script I'd like to run with cron it means I cant be entering the password each time. Note that the SSH keys work when I run the script from my user, but then the backup doesn't work as some of the file locations are permission denied.

I am backing up to a storage box with Hetzner.

My Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

LOG="/var/log/borg/backup.log"
BACKUP_USER="XXXXXXX"
REPOSITORY_DIR="backups/Node1"
REPOSITORY="ssh://${BACKUP_USER}@${BACKUP_USER}.your-storagebox.de:23/./${REPOSITORY_DIR}"
exec > >(tee -i ${LOG})
exec 2>&1

echo "###### Backup started: $(date) ######"

echo "Transfer files ..."
BORG_PASSPHRASE='XXXXXXXXXX' borg create -v --stats                   \
    $REPOSITORY::'{now:%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M}'  \
    /root                                \
    /etc                                 \
    /var/www                             \
    /home                                \
    --exclude /dev                       \
    --exclude /proc                      \
    --exclude /sys                       \
    --exclude /var/run                   \
    --exclude /run                       \
    --exclude /lost+found                \
    --exclude /mnt                       \
    --exclude /var/lib/lxcfs

echo "###### Backup ended: $(date) ######"
```

Answer (score 0):

I just copied my SSH private key to the root user and now it works.

`cp /home/user/.ssh/rsa_pub /root/.ssh/rsa_pub`